# “Incentive” used in a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence

I just searched the meaning of “incentive” and I have a question regarding making sentence with the word “incentive”.

This is my sentence “The extra money for hardworking employees is **my** incentive to work hard.” Is it ok to use **“my incentive”** or is it better/more common to say **“an incentive for me to work hard”**?

Thank you!

[Corrected]

Answer (score 1):

> “The extra money for hardworking employees is my incentive to work hard.”

This means "The thing that motivates me is that other people get money for working hard."

> “The extra money is my incentive to work hard.”

This means that you are motivated to work hard by extra money.

Comment: Interesting... kinda relate to the structure of the sentence? May I wonder then what does “the extra money for hardworking employees is the incentive for me to work hard” mean.

Answer (score 1):

Possessive determiners are not used all that often with 'incentive/s' (see [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+incentive+to%2Cour+incentive+to%2Ctheir+incentive+to%2Can+incentive+to%2Cas+our+incentive%2Cas+an+incentive&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20incentive%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20incentive%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheir%20incentive%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20incentive%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20our%20incentive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20an%20incentive%3B%2Cc0)), but [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incentive) gives one example sentence (though it's not totally clear whether the phrase 'their incentives' applies to the incentivisers or those so incentivised):

> *That way, their incentives will be provided through wealth rather than
> income at risk.* Times, Sunday Times (2017)

So

- *The extra money for hardworking employees is my incentive to work hard.*

is totally acceptable; using '... an incentive for me to work hard' would of course suggest that there may well be other incentives involved.

Answer (score 0):

"The extra money for hardworking workers is an incentive for me to work hard" makes more sense seeing as an incentive doesn't necessarily apply to you as individual but to everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry, Carly, I can't agree with you. There is absolutely nothing wrong with "The extra money ... is my incentive to work hard". I find "for hardworking workers" very clumsy, though, because of the repetition of 'work'. I would suggest "given to hardworking employees".

Comment: I agree the sentence is clumsy but singling out the incentive part only I guess it’s a matter of opinion. I wouldn’t use “my incentive” but each to their own I guess.

Comment: I think you're right, carly, we all have our preferences. By the way the downvote wasn't mine.

Comment: @BoldBen thank you for pointing out that! I have corrected my original post. May I wonder that would you choose “my incentive” or “the incentive for me” in this context?

Comment: @carlym Neither me. I upvoted it since I really didn’t understand why there was a downvote... Thank you!

Comment: The word use should reflect it as the management's incentive to the employee. I would also modify it slightly to "...an incentive to me for working hard"

Comment: @Coco For me they are two different things. "my incentive to work hard" implies that it is your only incentive whereas "an incentive for me to work hard" implies that you have other incentives as well, perhaps job satisfaction, the respect of your colleagues or an inherent tendency to avoid idleness. You could however say "_the_ incentive for me to work hard" which would also imply that it was the only incentive. The phrases "my incentive to work hard" and "_the_ incentive for me to work hard" are exactly equivalent, however, and I would be hard put to choose between them.